# Suppressing *some* language-specific changes in biblatex

Tags: biblatex, languages

I need to suppress some language-specific adaptations `babel` and `biblatex` produce from my `.bib`-entries.

This is the relevant part of my header

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[
  style=authoryear-icomp,
  maxnames=2,
  backend=bibtex,
  safeinputenc,]{biblatex}
```

Now

```
@book(Platts, 
key={Platts},
author={John T. Platts},
title={A Grammar of the Urd\=u or Hind\=ust\=an\={\i} Language},
    publisher={Crosby Lockwood and Son}, 
address={London},
year={1920},
)
```

produces

> Platts, John T. (1920): A Grammar of the Urdu or Hindustani Language.
>   London: Crosby Lockwood und Son.

(macrons in the right place, no worries about that).

How do I prevent `biblatex` from changing "and" to "und" in the publisher field?
I've tried the `language` and `origlanguage` fields, but they only work if `babel=english` is loaded, and when I do that, the whole bibliography style changes to English.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quoting from section 2.3.4 of the `biblatex` manual (emphasis added):

> The fields `institution`, `organization`, `publisher`, and `location`
>   are literal lists in terms of § 2.2. This also applies to
>   `origlocation`, `origpublisher` and to the field aliases `address`
>   and `school`. All of these fields may contain a list of items
>   separated by the keyword ‘`and`’. *If they contain a literal ‘`and`’,
>   it must be wrapped in braces.*

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[
  style=authoryear-icomp,
  maxnames=2,
  backend=bibtex,
  safeinputenc,]{biblatex}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book(Platts, 
key={Platts},
author={John T. Platts},
title={A Grammar of the Urd\=u or Hind\=ust\=an\={\i} Language},
    publisher={Crosby Lockwood {and} Son}, 
address={London},
year={1920},
)
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\nocite{*}

\begin{document}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: ouch! I should have thought of the braces, that did it, of course. Thanks a bunch!